# JavaScript / как сохранять данные?

Tags: javascript

```
var i=+(prompt("сколько всего слов ?"));
    while (n <= i){
    var slovo=prompt();
    var otvet=prompt();
    n++;
}

a1=slovo;
b1=otvet;
```

Как сделать так , чтобы slovo ,где нибудь сохранилось ? Суть этой программы тем что ты вводишь слова на англ и их перевод, а потом эти англ  слова рандомно выводится на экран и ты должен написать перевод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам можно использовать [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom'); //сохранить
localStorage.getItem('myCat'); //взять
```

По Вашему примеру:

```
var i=+(prompt("сколько всего слов ?"));
while (n<=i){
    var slovo=prompt();
    var otvet=prompt();
    localStorage.setItem(slovo, otvet);
    n++;
}
```

И тогда при вызове `localStorage.getItem('english');` будет возвращаться "английский". Естественно, если это было ранее введено.

Есть еще [куки](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie). По ссылкам есть примеры использования.

**UPDATE по комментарию**

Вам нужно внести `localValue` в тело цикла:

```
var i = (prompt("сколько всего слов ?"));
var n = 1;
while (n <= parseInt(i)) {
    var slovo = prompt("Введите слова:");
    var otvet = prompt("Введите перевод:");
    localStorage.setItem(slovo, otvet);
    n++;
}

n1 = 1; while (n1 <= i) {
    var localValue = localStorage.getItem(slovo);
    var answer = prompt(localValue);
    if (answer === localValue)
        alert("Правильно");
    n++;
}
```

Если Вы работаете в Google Chrome, можете нажать F12 -> Application -> (слева в разделе Storage) Local Storage -> ваш домен. Там будут данные, которые хранятся в вашем локальном хранилище. Как в Firefox-е открыть - не знаю точно, но примерно так же.

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
var i=+(prompt("сколько всего слов ?"));
n=1;
while (n<=i){
var slovo=prompt("Введите слова:");
var otvet=prompt("Введите перевод:");
localStorage.setItem(slovo, otvet);



n++;
}
var localValue = localStorage.getItem(slovo);

console.log(localValue);

n1=1;
while (n1<=i){
var a=prompt(localValue);
if (a==localValue) alert("Правильно")
n++;
}


localStorage.removeItem(slovo)





</script>` а как сделать так чтоб он сохранил и прошлые слова. у меня получается так что он последнее слова сохраняет или это через куки ?

Comment: Вы выводите только последнее слово, сейчас в апдейте покажу